# Grunt Uglify says No Files Created when using multiple tasks

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs

When using uglify with only one task it works correctly and generates my compressed file. When I split it into a dev task and a dist task it runs successfully but says "No Files Created".

here's the uglify section of my Gruntfile:

```
    uglify: {
      dev : {
        options: {
          mangle: false,
          compress: false,
          wrap: false,
          sourceMap: true,
          banner: '/*\n <%= pkg.name %> <%= pkg.version %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> \n*/\n'
        },
        build: {
          files: {
            'dist/js/app.min.js': [
              'src/js/zepto.min.js', 
              'src/js/app.js'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          mangle: true,
          compress: true,
          wrap: true,
          sourceMap: false,
          banner: '/*\n <%= pkg.name %> <%= pkg.version %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> \n*/\n'
        },
        build: {
          files: {
            'dist/js/app.min.js': [
            'src/js/zepto.min.js', 
            'src/js/app.js',
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

figured it out, no need for "build" and more:

```
uglify: {
  dev : {
    options: {
      mangle: false,
      compress: false,
      wrap: false,
      sourceMap: true,
      banner: '/*\n <%= pkg.name %> <%= pkg.version %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> \n*/\n'
    },
      files: {
        'dist/js/app.min.js': [
          'src/js/zepto.min.js', 
          'src/js/app.js'
        ]
      }

  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      mangle: true,
      compress: true,
      wrap: true,
      sourceMap: false,
      banner: '/*\n <%= pkg.name %> <%= pkg.version %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> \n*/\n'
    },
      files: {
        'dist/js/app.min.js': [
        'src/js/zepto.min.js', 
        'src/js/app.js',
        ]
      }

  }
},
```